# How do I load a file in a managed_file field inside an edit form?

Tags: forms, files

I'm building a custom module (Drupal 8) which implement new elements I called components. I have a component creation form which has a managed_file field which works well, it submits, save my image file at the correct path and create an entry in my managed_file table inside my database.

The problem is that I created an edit page for the so called components and I can't manage to load the component's image as the current image uploaded for this component in the manage_file field inside the edit form.

I've tried using #default_value and #value with the file fid and I tried inspecting the $form and $form_state to gather info but I can't manage to solve this.

Here is my field with the #default_value (not working, I've tried put the fid in array or not, as a string or as a number none working).

```
$form['thumbnail'] = [
        '#type' => 'managed_file',
        '#title' => $this->t('Thumbnail'),
        '#description' => $this->t('Upload a thumbnail of your component.'),
        '#required' => false,
        '#default_value' => ['42'],
        '#upload_location' => 'public://components_thumbnails/',
        '#upload_validators' => [
            'file_validate_is_image' => array(),
            'file_validate_extensions' => ['png jpeg gif jpg'],
            'file_validate_size' => array(5120000),
        ],
    ];
```

Did anybody manage to have an editable file field inside a form in Drupal 8? Do I have to switch from managed_file and use something else?

Comment: Maybe there is an answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34100546/drupal-8-add-an-image-field-from-a-buildform-with-preview

Comment: The default value should be the FID, not an array.

Comment: Thanks Jdrupal but the solution do not seems to work for me as it's not exaclty the same case.

Jaypand I've tried it again and this do not produce any result, did you already managed to get this working ? '#default_value' => 42,